# Unable to save checked state of input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an on/off button put in code as an input checkbox. I wasn't able to come up with a working code to `localStore` its checked/unchecked state as the user selects. I have also looked for similar solutions on stackoverflow but none worked; what am I doing wrong?

```js
$(function() {
  var data = localStorage.showning;
  $("input[name='saveee']")
    .prop('checked', data == 'true')
    .change(function() {
      localStorage.showning = $(this).prop("checked");
    });
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 16px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  background: #CCC;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background: #4CD964;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(11px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(11px);
  transform: translateX(11px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="background:black; width:100px; height:100px; padding:20px;">
  <p style="color:white;">on/off button:</p>
  <label class="switch">
    <input name="saveee" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

*Don't bother with the CSS, just check the HTML & JQ.*

Comment: Your code works fine for me (Chrome 67, Win 10) http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/m6wbx5tq. You should use `getItem()` and `setItem()` on localStorage for better compatibility, though.

Comment: Ok... it worked. I think it's time for me to get some sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get/set the localStorage's item properly. To set:

```
data.setItem('your-local-storage-key', true/or whatever your value);
```

To get the item:

```
data.getItem('your-local-storage-key');
```

More on `localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage